# How can I pass url params to templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to retrieve a page, but on the documentation, it only shows how to pass in parameters in the url, not the template url.

Is there anyway where it can be passed in the templateUrl?

Below is my code

```
 <div ui-view></div>
 <!-- We'll also add some navigation: -->
 <a ui-sref="contacts({contactId: 1})">State 1</a>
```

And the angular config:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('contacts', {
            url: "/states?myParam={contactId}",
            templateUrl: "states1.html"
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`templateUrl` can be a function that takes `stateParams` parameter:

```
.state('contacts', {
    url: "/states?myParam={contactId}",
    templateUrl: function(stateParams) {
        return "states" + stateParams.contactId + ".html";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want it?

The only reason I can think about is that you want to customize the template on the server-side based on the passed arguments. Which goes against the idea of templates :)

Templates should be generic enough.

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.